# Вызов метода API VК в цикле

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Не получается вызвать асинхронный метод API VK несколько раз в цикле с разными парметрами, подскажите как можно правильно это сделать? (при таком примере код виснет)

```
var id = N;
while (id < N){
  vk.request('users.get', {'user_ids' : id++, 'fields' : 'schools','access_token' : '#################'}, function(_o) {
  var res = JSON.stringify(_o);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  console.log(obj);
  id = id + 1;
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Ну, тут-то как раз понятно. У вас сначала `id = N`, затем вы его только увеличиваете (один раз при отсылке реквеста и зачем-то ещё раз при приходе ответа), и ждёте. когда же наконец станет `id < N`. Вам придётся ждать, пока значение `id` переполнится (если такое вообще бывает в js). [Кроме того, вы шлёте запросы, не дождавшись ответа, в практически бесконечном цикле. Но эо меньшая из проблем.]

Comment: @VladD подскажите, а как тогда правильно организовать вызов такого метода в цикле с параметрами?!

Comment: А что именно вы хотите? Опишите словами. С какими параметрами вы хотите вызвать API?

Comment: @VladD я хочу вызвать  допустим  10 раз ассинхронный метод API в цикле, чтоб получить пользователей с id от 1 до 10 к примеру. while (id < 10){vk.request('users.get', {'user_ids' : id, 'fields' : 'schools', 'access_token' : '#####'}, function(_o) {
var res1 = JSON.stringify(_o);
var obj = JSON.parse(res1);
console.log(obj);
});}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
function process(curr, max) {
    if (curr > max) return;
    vk.request('users.get',
               {
                   'user_ids' : curr,
                   'fields' : 'schools',
                   'access_token' : '#################'
               },
               function(_o) {
                   var res = JSON.stringify(_o);
                   var obj = JSON.parse(res);
                   console.log(obj);
                   process(curr+1, max);
               });
}

process(1, 10)
```

Но всё же, не забывайте проверять ошибки. Если вы будете посылать чересчур много запросов и игнорировать ошибки, вас скорее всего забанят.

Comment: да, спасибо большое, все работает, а как сделать задержку, чтоб функция к примеру process выполнялась  только каждые 1/3 секунды, а то по некоторым запросам выдает too many requests pers second(ограничение не больше 3 запросов в секунду)

Comment: @dimaborovski: например, можно вместо `process(curr+1, max);` вызывать `setTimeout(function() { process(curr+1, max) } , 333))`.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> var id = N;
> while (id < N){
> ```

Этот цикл вообще не выполняеся, не?

> ```
> id = id + 1;
> ```

А это надо убрать.